# Spacebar doesn't register when holding up and left with java's keylistener

Tags: java, keylistener, keyevent

When I hold up and left the program registers them fine. However, it won't register when I hit space. If you switch VK_LEFT to VK_RIGHT then proceed to hold right and up while hitting space it works fine.

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class Testing implements KeyListener {

    public boolean isUp;
    public boolean isLeft;

    public Testing() {
        JFrame application = new JFrame();

        application.addKeyListener(this);
        application.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        application.setSize(500, 500); 
        application.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Testing test = new Testing();
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP)
            isUp = true;
        else if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)
            isLeft = true;
        else if(isUp && isLeft && e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE)
            System.out.println("pew pew");
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP)
            isUp = false;
        else if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)
            isLeft = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

    }
}
```

It should register space while holding up and left like it does with up and right but it doesn't.

Comment: I can confirm this behavior, but it is only the VK_LEFT key that causes the issue.  Holding down VK_LEFT, only one other keyPressed will trigger.  Interestingly, holding down VK_LEFT, the keyPressed event will continuously trigger until another VK is pressed, then the new keyPressed event will trigger continuously, but the VK_LEFT keyPressed even will never trigger again until VK_LEFT is released.

Comment: I have determined that this behavior is being caused by a limitation in the keyboard hardware.  Using a Razer Blackwidow gaming keyboard that supports n-key rollover, all key presses are tracked correctly.  Using a cheap USB keyboard, the LEFT and UP direction keys when pressed simultaneously, prevent that keyboard from registering any other subsequent key presses.

Comment: I figured that's what it was but thanks for confirmation